# Laravel Activity Log won't work on Update

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-8, activitylog

**I'm using SPATIE laravel-activitylog I followed all the instructions but still it only log the Create function not update while using it on a Modal**

My Modal

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;

class Contact extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, LogsActivity;
    protected $fillable = [
        'comp_name',
        'cont_name',
        'cont_email',
        'cont_number',
        'created_by',
        'updated_by',
    ];
        // spatie activitylog
    protected static $logFillable = true;
    protected static $logOnlyDirty = true;
    protected static $logName='users'; // default
}
```

My Controller

```
 Contact::where('id',$input['id'])->update($data);
 $retrnArray = array('status'=>1,'msg'=>'Updated Successfully');
```

Comment: And you are updating new information and not just the same model without changes?

Comment: @NicklasKevinFrank I am updating a number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Update* with writing in DB but **NOT** writing in ActivityLogs will look like this:

```
User::where("id", 1)->update($data);
```

The *Update* with writing in DB and **ALSO** writing in ActivityLogs will look like this:

```
User::where("id", 1)->first()?->update($data); //if you are using php >= 8
User::where("id", 1)->firstOrFail()->update($data); // Good using php >= 5.6
User::find(1)?->update($data); //This also works as find("your id") also returns the model that it was able to found, it also returns null so check it on null or use nullsafe operator.
```

It's important to load model to make ActivityLogs correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed my query. we should use Eloquent query.

```
$contact = Contact::find($input['id']);
$contact->cont_email = $input['cont_email'];
$contact->cont_number = $input['cont_number'];           
$contact->save();

$retrnArray = array('status'=>1,'msg'=>'Updated Successfully');
```

Comment: kinda weird that we need to use "find" first and not just a simple grab and "update" but it works sooo...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the default log options does not include all Model`s field. You can describe fields that needs logging or use the wildcard to fire logging for every field changes. According to [documentation](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v4/advanced-usage/logging-model-events) example (in your Model Class):

```
public function getActivitylogOptions(): LogOptions
{
    return LogOptions::defaults()->logOnly(['*']);
    // To avoid hardcoding you could use logAll() method
    // return LogOptions::defaults()->logAll();
}
```

Comment: Bad luck, It still not working. Also, i used "logAll()"